# How to make a conditional join based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, join

I have a tables:

```
Activities{ActivityId, ActivityTypeId, CreatedByUserId, ItemId, FollowId}
Items{ItemId, Title}
Followings{FollowId, FollowerId, FollowingId}
```

In `Activity` table `ItemId` or `FollowId` can be null (never both).
Now I need somehow based on or `ActivityTypeId` or if one of `ItemId` or `FollowId` if null to make join to `Items` table or `Followings` table.

How to write this kind of conditional query?

If `ItemId` is null I need to made join to `Followings` table.
If `ItemId` is not null I need to made join to `Items` table.

I also asked about `ActivityTypeId` because it's maybe easier to check activity type and based on that to make a join to Items or Followings table.

Comment: I don't understand this: `Now I need somehow based on or ActivityTypeId or if one of ItemId or FollowId if null to make join to Items table or Followings table.`

Comment: What you want to see in result set (what columns)?

Comment: All from Activities, Items and Followings I think it's easier. In application I can based on Type to read different columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of the following will return different results. The first will return every relationship between (actvities and items) and (activities and followings). The second will return every combination of relationship between (actvities and items) and (activities and followings). Try them both and see which works best for you.

(Note: I haven't tested these - I wrote them freehand - there may be syntax errors)

```
SELECT  a.ActivityId, 
        a.ActivityTypeId,
        a.CreatedByUserId,
        i.ItemId,
        i.Title,
        null as FollowId,
        null as FollowerId,
        null as FollowingId
FROM    Activities a INNER JOIN Items i ON a.ItemId = i.ItemId
UNION ALL
SELECT  a.ActivityId, 
        a.ActivityTypeId,
        a.CreatedByUserId,
        null as ItemId,
        null as Title,
        f.FollowId,
        f.FollowerId,
        f.FollowingId
FROM    Activities a INNER JOIN Followings f ON a.FollowId = f.FollowId
```

OR:

```
SELECT  a.ActivityId, 
        a.ActivityTypeId,
        a.CreatedByUserId,
        i.ItemId,
        i.Title,
        f.FollowId,
        f.FollowerId,
        f.FollowingId
FROM    Activities a 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Items i ON a.ItemId = i.ItemId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Followings f ON a.FollowId = f.FollowId
```

Comment: @1110 which one is optimized way?